# Как в ExtJS переключить язык интерфеса панели и грид

Tags: extjs

Имеется панель типа

```js
Ext.define('CarCatalog.view.CarCatalogView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 360,
    padding: 10,
    alias: 'widget.carCatalogView',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
        {
            itemId: 'rugrid',
            xtype: 'carGridView',
            region: 'center'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'headerCarView',
            region: 'north',
            height: 50
        },
        {
            xtype: 'searchCarView',
            title: 'Поиск',
            region: 'east',
            width: 200,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'treeCarView',
            title: 'Тип документа',
            region: 'west',
            width: 250,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'infoCarView',
            region: 'south',
            height: 25
        }
    ],
});
```

Как в код добавить две кнопки переключения языка, чтобы по клику можно было сменить все items: на другие
Можно-ли по клику на кнопке сменить свойство  text: 'Tipul documentului', на  text: 'Тип документа' в таблице

```
{
    text: 'Tipul documentului',
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'name',
    width: 200,
    editor: {
        xtype:'textfield'
    }
},
```

Comment: Подскажите, актуальнен ли еще вопрос и какой у Вас extjs, используете ли Вы extjs 5 и выше версии с возможностью (MVVM и data bind)?